# How to test this CSV import rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, csv, rspec

I have no idea where to start with testing this rake task. Do I need stubs? If so, how to use them? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
desc "Import CSV file"
  task :import => [:environment] do
    data = "db/data.csv" 
    headers = CSV.open(data, 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
    cs = headers[2..-1].map { |c| Model1.where(name: c).first_or_create }
    ls = Model2.find_ls

    csv_contents = CSV.read(photos)
    csv_contents.shift

    csv_contents.each do |row|
      p = Model2.where(id: row[0], f_name: row[1]).first_or_create
      p_d = FastImage.size(p.file.url(:small))
      p.update_attributes(dimensions: p_d)

      row[2..-1].each_with_index do |ls, i|
        unless ls.nil?
          ls.split(',').each { |l|
          cl = Model3.where(name: l.strip, model_1_id: cs[i].id).first_or_create
          Model4.where(p_id: p.id, model_3_id: cl.id).first_or_create
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

**1) Happy-path test(s)**

Rake tasks as such are a pain to test. Extract the body of the rake task into a class:

whatever.rake

```
desc "Import CSV file"
  task :import => [:environment] do
    CSVImporter.new.import "db/data.csv"
  end
end
```

lib/csv_importer.rb

```
class CsvImporter
  def import(data)
    headers = CSV.open(data, 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
    cs = headers[2..-1].map { |c| Model1.where(name: c).first_or_create }
    ls = Model2.find_ls

    csv_contents = CSV.read(photos)
    csv_contents.shift

    csv_contents.each do |row|
      p = Model2.where(id: row[0], f_name: row[1]).first_or_create
      p_d = FastImage.size(p.file.url(:small))
      p.update_attributes(dimensions: p_d)

      row[2..-1].each_with_index do |ls, i|
        unless ls.nil?
          ls.split(',').each { |l|
          cl = Model3.where(name: l.strip, model_1_id: cs[i].id).first_or_create
          Model4.where(p_id: p.id, model_3_id: cl.id).first_or_create
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now it's easy to write a test that calls `CSVImporter.new.import` on a test file (that's why `import` takes the file as a parameter instead of hardcoding it) and expects the results. If it's reasonable to import `db/data.csv` in the test environment, you can do that in a test if you want. You probably only need one test like this. No stubs are required.

**2) Edge and error cases**

There is a lot of logic here which, for simplicity and speed, you'll want to test without creating actual model objects. That is, yes, you'll want to stub. `Model2.find_ls` and `FastImage.size` are already easy to stub. Let's extract a method to make the other model calls easy to stub:

```
class CsvImporter
  def import(data)
    headers = CSV.open(data, 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
    cs = headers[2..-1].map { |c| Model1.first_or_create_with(name: c) }
    ls = Model2.find_ls

    csv_contents = CSV.read(photos)
    csv_contents.shift

    csv_contents.each do |row|
      p = Model2.first_or_create_with(id: row[0], f_name: row[1])
      p_d = FastImage.size(p.file.url(:small))
      p.update_attributes(dimensions: p_d)

      row[2..-1].each_with_index do |ls, i|
        unless ls.nil?
          ls.split(',').each { |l|
          cl = Model3.first_or_create_with(name: l.strip, model_1_id: cs[i].id)
          Model4.first_or_create_with(p_id: p.id, model_3_id: cl.id)
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/concerns/active_record_extensions.rb

```
module ActiveRecordExtensions
  def first_or_create_with(attributes)
    where(attributes).first_or_create
  end
end
```

and include the module in all of the models that need it.

Now it's easy to stub all of the model methods so you can write tests that simulate any database situation you like.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry for delay, yes this is great thank you. I am just starting with RSpec and I will have to see how to actually test each of the components but this should definitely help.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Can you help me this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181552/writing-testcase-for-csv-import-rake-task

Comment: Nice, I can just create a custom CSV file and test the behaviour of the class using the test csv and use the actual csv file in the rake task.