# Writing TestCase for CSV import rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple rails application where I import data from csv into my rails app which is functioning properly, **but I have no idea where to start with testing this rake task, as well as where in a modular rails app**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Hint**

> My Rails structure is a little different from traditional rails structures, as I have written a Modular Rails App. My structure is in the picture below:

[image: My Rails Structure]

**engines/csv_importer/lib/tasks/web_import.rake**

The rake task that imports from csv..

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

namespace :web_import do
  desc 'Import users from csv'

  task users: :environment do
    url = 'http://blablabla.com/content/people.csv'
    # I forced encoding so avoid UndefinedConversionError "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
    csv_string = open(url).read.force_encoding('UTF-8')

    counter = 0
    duplicate_counter = 0

    user = []
    CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      next unless row[:name].present? && row[:email_address].present?
      user = CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
      if user.persisted?
        counter += 1
      else
        duplicate_counter += 1
      end
    end
    p "Email duplicate record: #{user.email_address} - #{user.errors.full_messages.join(',')}" if user.errors.any?

    p "Imported #{counter} users, #{duplicate_counter} duplicate rows ain't added in total"
  end
end
```

**Mounted csv_importer in my parent structure**

This makes the csv_importer engine available in the root of the application.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount CsvImporter::Engine => '/', as: 'csv_importer'
end
```

**To correctly migrate in the root of the application, I added initializer**

**/engines/csv_importer/lib/csv_importer/engine.rb**

```
module CsvImporter
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace CsvImporter

    # This enables me to be able to correctly migrate the database from the parent application.
    initializer :append_migrations do |app|
      unless app.root.to_s.match(root.to_s)
        config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |p|
          app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << p
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So with this explanation am able to run rails app like every other rails application. I explained this so anyone who will help will understand what to help me with as regards writing test for the rake task inside the engine.

**What I have done as regards writing TEST**

```
task import: [:environment] do
  desc 'Import CSV file'
  task test: :environment do
    # CSV.import 'people.csv'
    Rake::Task['app:test:db'].invoke
  end
end
```

How do someone write test for a rake task in a modular app? Thanks!

Comment: @dave-schweisguth Someone asked me to tag and request for your help as regards this. My apologies if this is not proper

Comment: No problem. It was nice of them to think of me. Who was it? In any case, Daryll Santos has already suggested the exact approach that I would suggest.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I still don't get it though. I don't know if he says I should refactor my solution or he is referring to writing test. Am just confused..

Comment: Yes, you should refactor so it's easier to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with engines, but is there a way to just put the CSV importing logic into it's own class?

```
namespace :web_import do
  desc 'Import users from csv'

  task users: :environment do
    WebImport.new(url: 'http://blablabla.com/content/people.csv').call
  end
end

class WebImport # (or whatever name you want)
  def initialize(url) ... end

  def call
    counter, CSV parse, etc...
  end
end
```

That way you can bump into the Rails console to do the `WebImport` and you can also do a test isolating `WebImport`. When you do Rake tasks and Jobs (Sidekiq etc), you want to make the Rake task act as as thin a wrapper as possible around the actual meat of the code (which is in this case CSV parsing). Separate the "trigger the csv parse" code from the "actually parse the csv" code into their own classes or files.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Whether it's code in your build system, or a view, or a controller, or an executable... decouple the work from the surrounding code by turning it into a class. Then you can thoroughly test that class in isolation. You may want to also make sure `rake web_import` still works, but that can be a very simple test to ensure the linkages work. As a bonus, `WebImport` can be used elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @DaryllSantos if I get you right, I should refactor my csv rake import task using Classes ? And that will help me to easily write a TestCase to the rake task

Comment: Can you please refactor a little further your solution so I can understand ?

Comment: Okay, what part is confusing? I move everything inside the Rake task to its own class, so I can call the class by it's own. Check out articles on service objects in Ruby/Rails.

Comment: Okay. clearer now. Solved. So I will proceed and write TestCase for the rake task now. However, if you have a preference to writing TestCase for this solution, I will be glad. Thanks